# Open applications in the background in OS X, I don't want my focus taken from me. Respect my Focus!

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, unix, multitasking

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.4 on a 2014 Mac Mini.

I'm often running 10-14 apps at one time as I work writing reports, word/excel/Adobe/Safari/iTunes/calendar/etc...

Frequently I want to open another app, I want it to open in the background and go back to word/excel and keep working, but the launching app takes away my focus, sometimes 2 or 3 times. once for the splash screen, once for the open dialogue window, and again after I click 'new document'.

Another situation, I update an app in the background, like 1Password (beta) and every step it takes my focus back to the app being updated.

Is there anything I can do with Unix/Terminal, etc. to force all app activity to be done in the background, or to keep OS to respect my focus?

Comment: God I wish this could be resolved. I launch apps from spotlight and it always kills my work flow to have the app steal back my attention after 2-10 seconds of loading.

Comment: On Monterey (but I think it started before) I've suddenly had the exact opposite behavior (ie. exactly what the OP requests) but I have no idea which setting (or hidden preference) I used.

Answer (score 5):

To launch an app in Finder in the background (hidden) you can use a simple **Automator** service. Open Automator app, select a *service* that accepts files or folders in Finder and add a **Run Shell Script** action with following contents:

[image: Automator service]

```
for f in "$@"
do
    open "$f" --hide
done
```

Save the service as **Open in background**. Open **System Preferences./ Keyboard / Shortcuts / Services**, find your new service and assign a keyboard shortcut you desire. I chose a handy <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Close System Preferences and test the service and the shortcut.

[image: open in background]

Nice thing about this is that it works with apps as well as documents.

Answer (score 1):

Working on macOS 12.1 (Monterey) with another flag option:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    open "$f" -gj
done
```

see this post for more information: [Open app in background from Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260254/open-app-in-background-from-terminal)

Comment: couldn't comment because no reputation...

Comment: It would be helpful to future users that come across this answer if you could [edit] in a summary of the information in case the link becomes broken.