# Open app in background from Terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to open an app in the background from the Terminal by using the `-g` or `--background` flags like so

```
open -g -a Franz
```

Unfortunately, the app isn't opening in the background. I've also tried the `j` flag, which is supposed to hide the app, according to the help:

```
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
      By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.  
      If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
Options: 
      -a                Opens with the specified application.
      -b                Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
      -e                Opens with TextEdit.
      -t                Opens with default text editor.
      -f                Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
      -F  --fresh       Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
      -R, --reveal      Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
      -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
          --args        All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
      -n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
      -j, --hide        Launches the app hidden.
      -g, --background  Does not bring the application to the foreground.
      -h, --header      Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them.
```

The app opens in the foreground as if the I had simply called

```
open -a Franz
```

Any idea why this doesn't work and an alternative?

Comment: I've tested it with several applications on macOS 10.12.5 and it works well. The problem is maybe related to the Franz application.

Comment: I’m having the same issue, where certain apps don’t respect the flags. I can open `Messages` in the background, but trying to open `Books` with the same flags opens it in the foreground. Annoying that Apple’s own apps don’t work with this…

Comment: For future readers: the conflicting reports in this Q&A are probably caused by exactly which app is being opened. For example, Google Chrome refuses to respect either `-g` or `-j` (or `-gj` for that matter), but Firefox and Safari work perfectly with just `-g`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you call the command open with `--hide (-j)` it works (at least in macOS Sierra). For instance

```
open -j -a /Applications/Skype.app
```

Also, the `-g` flag helps some

```
open -gj -a /Applications/Skype.app
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this answer does not work for more recent versions of MacOs, as Catalina

Comment: Second one worked on the Catalina

Comment: `open -gj -a "Name of Application"` works perfectly

Comment: None of these work on Ventura 13.1.

Answer (score 9):

As of writing (10.14.3 Mojave), the correct answer is:

```sh
open -a /Applications/Skype.app -gj
```

If you do

```sh
man open
```

you can see that

> -g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.
>
> -j  Launches the app hidden.

Comment: Thanks. Not on Mojave yet, but will keep in mind for when I upgrade.

Comment: Does not work for me (10.14.6 Mojave)

Comment: That doesn’t really address the question—they’re trying to open the app in the background, not hidden.

Comment: Works for me with macOS 10.14.6 (18G3020) for NetNewsWire.app: The app is launched and immediately hidden without the screen flickering or something like that.

Comment: The OP states that they have already tried -g and -j.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `-j` and `-g` before the `-a`

For example:

```
open -gja /Applications/Calendar.app
```

Comment: OP states very clearly that the -j flag _does not work_.

Comment: Right, essentially it works only in combination with the `-g (--background) and -j (--hide) Flag`