# How to open an app in the background in MacOS monterey with -g or -j flag?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, bash, monterey

I want to know how to run an app without showing it in foreground or just in the background using `open -g` or `open -j` or `open -gj` command in MacOS Monterey.

**After referring to this answer:** [Open app in background from Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260254/open-app-in-background-from-terminal)

I tried to run an electron app using open -gj Appname but it's opening the app in the foreground.

I also tried all the variations given in the answer above, but it's not opening in the background.

The commands I am using is:

```
open -j /Applications/AppName.app
open -g /Applications/AppName.app
open -jg /Applications/AppName.app
```

However, some apps such as Sourcetree and Safari is opening in the background when using the same command.

But none of it is working in some apps such as VSCode and instead opening the app normally like open -a appname would do.

I read that some apps don't obey the -g or -j flag but no solution to how to force it.

Any idea why this doesn't work and how to force it?

**Note: I'll be writing a bash script to run this command when the app is not opened**

**Bash Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

ZLURI_PROCESS=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -ci zluri)
OSQUERY_PROCESS=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -ci osquery)

if [[ $ZLURI_PROCESS -gt 0 ]] && [[ $OSQUERY_PROCESS -gt 0 ]]
  then
    echo "running"
  else
    echo "not running"
    open -jg zluri
fi
```

Comment: It could be that Electron apps don't support the background instruction. Can you describe the entire workflow for which you need this app opened hidden?

Comment: So, first from an audit scripts that will run in Kandji, it will check if our app process in running or not using ps aux command. If the number of process is 0, it means the process is not running. So, in that case, the script should run open -gj AppName.

So currently I'll the bash script as well in the question.

Comment: Added the bash script to the question.

Comment: Would it be simpler just to use a LaunchAgent to keep the app running?